# How to solve Problem 18, Chapter 5, Spivak Calculus?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

I have been working on Spivak's calculus book. I am currently on chapter 5: limits.

The problem: proof that if $ f(x)=x$ for $x$ rational and $f(x)=-x$ for $x$ irrational, then $\lim_{x \to a }f(x)$ does not exist if $a\neq0$.

My solution:

I split the limit into to sequences $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)= l_1$ where $x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and then $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)= l_2$ where $x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, so if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)= L$ exists, then $l_1=l_2=L$. The limit should be the same regardless of how I approach a.

Now:

1. For $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, I have that if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then if $\epsilon= \delta$, $|f(x)-a|<\epsilon$, so $l_1=a$
2. For $x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, I have that if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then if $\epsilon= \delta$, $|x-a|=|-(x-a)|=|f(x)+a|<\epsilon$, so $l_2=-a$.

For 
 $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ to exist then $l_1=l_2=L$ and that only happens for $a=0$.

Is this reasoning right?

Comment: But have you proved that the limit exists *only* if $\ell_1=\ell_2$? Uniqueness of limit was proved (in an exercise) with the ordinary limit assumptions (namely, looking at *all* $x$ sufficiently close to $a$).

Comment: What is $\mathbb{Q}'$? Do you mean $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: If you add one more point (uniqueness of limit) in the last step in each point, then it will be fine.  In the contrapositive proof, the logic is good.:)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I fixed the sets

Comment: @TedShifrin and  I have proven that if $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = L$,  $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=L$ and $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ then $L=M$. Is that the uniqueness proof you mean?

Comment: @GNUSupporter: do you mean mentioning the previous (written up) proof for each point?

Comment: @Amphiaraos Sorry for my unclear comment.  I mean the transition from $|f(x)+a|<\epsilon$ to $l_2=-a$ (and similarly for $l_1=a$).  It follows from the fact that $\Bbb{R}$ has unique limits: $$\require{enclose}
{\Large\enclose{circle}[mathcolor="red"]{a}}
{\underleftrightarrow{\text{unique limit in }\Bbb{R}}}
{\Large\enclose{circle}[mathcolor="red"]{\ell_1}}$$

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with your exposition, because you have implicitly used the fact that **the rationals are dense in the reals**, and similarly, **the irrationals are dense in the reals**.  That is to say, for every pair of $a, b \in \mathbb R$ with $a < b$, there exists a rational number $p/q \in \mathbb Q$ such that $a < p/q < b$.  Furthermore, there also exists an irrational number $c \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ such that $a < c < b$.  You need these properties to state that, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there **exists a neighborhood** $\delta$ around $a$ such that whenever $0 < |x - a| < \delta$, $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

To make it clear, suppose that instead of $\mathbb Q$, we dealt with $\mathbb Z$.  In other words, suppose $$g(x) = \begin{cases} x, & x \in \mathbb Z \\ -x, & x \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Z. \end{cases}$$  Does this function have a limit at, say, $x = 1/2$?  The answer is **yes**.  Does this function have a limit at, say, $x = 1$?  Again, the answer is **yes**.  Why is this function qualitatively different than the original function $f$ in your question?  If I applied your argument to $g$, where does it break down?

Comment: Your explanation made me understand better about denseness. I have read it in the book but didn't know how to formalise it.
However, I can't apply the same reasoning to $g(x)$. If I approach $g(x)$ through $\mathbb{Z}$ I can't make $\epsilon$ as small as I want. So I will have to use another approach. Using $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ to approach $ \epsilon$ $g(x)$ doesn't change so the limit exists for both points (1, $1/2$)

Comment: Spivak formalizes the density of rationals and irrationals a few chapters later, if I remember correctly, but expects it to be taken for granted here.

Comment: I think these ideas of density are not new to students, the terminology "dense in the reals" may be new. Such obvious facts can be used directly without explicitly stating them. The essential problem is that most students don't know that these properties have far reaching consequences.